# Passing variables from multiple javascript functions to another?

Tags: javascript

Have two dropdown lists where I'm attempting to pass the selected values for both to another function.  Know the way I'm doing it isn't correct but been looking at it for so long can't see the probably simple solution.

```
  d3.select("#parameterType").on("change", function() 
    {
        var selectedParameter = this.value;
        console.log(selectedParameter);
        filterData(selectedParameter);
    });


    d3.select("#dateTimeTaken").on("change", function() 
    {   
        var selectedMonth = this.value;
        console.log(selectedMonth);
        filterData(selectedMonth)
    });


    function filterData(selectedParameter,selectedMonth)
    {
        console.log(selectedParameter);
        console.log(selectedMonth);
    }
```

Can anyone help point me in the right direction?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I suggest retrieving the selected values in the function you are trying to pass the parameters to. Something like this:

```
function filterData()
{
   var selectedParameter = document.getElementById("parameterType").value;
   var selectedMonth = document.getElementById("dateTimeTaken").value;
   console.log(selectedParameter);
   console.log(selectedMonth);
}
```

and call the function whenever any one of the selected values change.

```
d3.select("#parameterType").on("change", function() { filterData(); });

d3.select("#dateTimeTaken").on("change", function() { filterData(); });
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this approach:

Keep track of `selectedParameter` and `selectedMonth` outside of the function. In the `onchange` handlers, set the appropriate variable and then call the `filterData` function with no arguments. Then `filterData` checks if both variables are set and, if so, does something with them.

Code:

```
var filterData = (function () {
    var selectedParameter, selectedMonth;
    d3.select("#parameterType").on("change", function() 
    {
        selectedParameter = this.value;
        filterData();
    });

    d3.select("#dateTimeTaken").on("change", function() 
    {   
        selectedMonth = this.value;
        filterData();
    });

    function filterData()
    {
        if (selectedParameter === undefined || selectedMonth === undefined) {
            console.log("Both variables not set yet.");
            return;
        }
        console.log("Both variables are set!");
    }
    return filterData;
})();
```

I wrapped it in a closure so the variables don't leak into the global scope, and made the closure return the `filterData` function so it can be callable outside of just the closure.

Comment: Thank you Claudiu your approach worked perfectly too but can only accept one:)

Comment: no worries! GwynnBleidd's answer makes a lot more sense anyway.

Answer (score 0):

make a global variable by changeing var selectedParameter = this.value; to just selectedParameter = this.value; with no var.

Comment: Globals are overkill. It's much easier to declare a local variable in the outer scope, where all three functions can see it.

Comment: i guess your right but why are they overkills? im new to javascript.

Comment: [Why are global variables considered bad practice?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10525582/why-are-global-variables-considered-bad-practice-javascript)