# cache factory or just normal object

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I am creating a mid-sized angular app and have a need to store data and use it at the end of the user journey to send off to the server (company security policy is one transport of customer data - unless 100% unavoidable - dont ask!)

so I've been doing a little bit of reading as still quite new to angular and think I've decided the best and cleanest way to do this is to have a "dataFactory" or service so as not to pollute the app with a "master controller" etc, etc

my question is, within this service, do I just have a normal variable which I can assign key:values to or is it better to create a cacheFactory within the service to store the data?

what are the pros/cons of each?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to create a `service` to store data.

**[Globals are ever a bad practice](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10525582/why-are-global-variables-considered-bad-practice-javascript)** - and this is the same for a `normal object` lost somewhere in your code.

**Solution below:**

```
// service
myApp.service('controllerSharingData', function() {
  var __variables = {};

  return {
   get: function(varname) {
    return (typeof __variables[varname] !== 'undefined') ? __variables[varname] : false;
   },
   set: function(varname, value) {
    __variables[varname] = value;
   }
  };
});

// controllers
myApp.controller('IndexCtrl', function($scope, controllerSharingData) {
  controllerSharingData.set('toto', 'hello world');
});

myApp.controller('ListCtrl', function($scope, controllerSharingData) {
  alert(controllerSharingData.get('toto'));
});
```

Comment: service over a factory despite both being singleton?

Comment: also what you have given me is what i meant by a "Normal variable" im new to angular, not javascript, i know fullwell the evils of globals!

Comment: This doesn't really address the question which was cachefactory vs object ?