# Python Need Access to variable created in a function from another function

Tags: python, python-3.x, tkinter

As i have set search term to global for the first function - shouldnt the second function be able to access it - if not how would i get this to work?

```
import sys
import os.path
from tkinter import *
import math

def setupsearch():
    exist = os.path.isfile('messages.txt')
    if exist == True:
        global searchterm
        gui2 = Toplevel(master=gui)
        Label(gui2, text = "Search Term").grid(row = 0)
        searchterm = Entry(gui2).grid(row = 1)
        Button(gui2, text="Search", command = search).grid(row = 2)
    else:
        labelprint = "No Stored Messages"
        add = Label(gui, text = labelprint, width = 30)
        add.grid(row = 2, column =2)

def search():
    searchterm = 
    with open('messages.txt', 'r') as inF:
        i = 1
        for line in inF:
            if searchterm in line:
                print("found it in line " + str(i))
                i = i + 1
            else:
                print("Not in line " + str(i))
                i = i + 1  

gui = Tk()

Button(gui, text="Retriever", command=setupsearch).grid(row = 5, column = 0)

mainloop( )
```

Comment: Note that `searchterm` is not what you think, if you place a debugging `print(searchterm)` in your code you'll see with your eyes.

Comment: Further, the other answer are good solutions for your question about global variable, but not as good with respect to your problem, that is different from what you assume. Summary, (1) in callbacks use `lambda: f(x)` to pass around your values, (2) `Tkinter.Entry()` returns a widget, not the value of the text.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your `setupsearch` use

```
        Button(gui2,
               text="Search",
               command = lambda: search(thesearchterm)).grid(row = 2)
```

and of course modify the definition of `search`

```
def search(searchterm):
    ...
```

Note that I used `lambda: search(the_searchterm)` for a good reason, as `searchterm = Entry(...)` is a widget.  Please read a tutorial on `Tkinter.Entry` or simply, from the shell prompt, use `man Entry` (you must have installed the docs for tk, of course).

Answer (score 1):

Each function that wants to change the value of the `searchterm` global variable needs to declare `global searchterm`.  The `global` statement doesn't change properties of the variable itself—rather, it changes properties of the function, specifically the way the current function sets and gets values for the variable name in question.

You can get away with accessing a global variable from inside a function, without declaring it global, provided (a) there is no local variable of the same name to conflict with it, and (b) you don't need to change its global value.

If you don't say `global searchterm` but then assign something to `searchterm`,  the function will simply create a local variable of that name.

Comment: @zaxvo When i change it to global searchterm in search() function it returns the "TypeError: 'in <string>' requires string as left operand, not NoneType"

Answer (score 0):

You want to begin your second function by stating:

```
def search():
    global searchterm
    ## rest of function goes here
```

Then you'll be able to access the global variable from within `search()`

With that being said...I'm sure you know that, in general, having global variables is a bad idea.

Comment: why is having global variables is a bad idea.

Comment: @MatthewStevens-Keane - The advice given here applies to almost all languages, including Python: http://stackoverflow.com/a/10525602/2555451

Comment: When i change it to global searchterm in search() function it returns "TypeError: 'in <string>' requires string as left operand, not NoneType"

Comment: Because then any function anywhere in your program could affect that variable. This might be what you want, but in general it's bad practice. (Of course, there are exceptions to the rule)
In your case I would have the first line in `search()` be a read of the search term from the UI field. Avoids the global variable and makes the structure more obvious. I'm unfamiliar with Tkinter lib, but [my best guess is] it would be something like `searchterm = Entry(gui.gui2).grid(row=1)` so it's clear where you're getting that value from.

Comment: @zaxvo how would i get the first line in search() to be a read of the search term from the UI field.