# get the value of variable inside other function javascript

Tags: javascript, php, youtube-api, youtube-javascript-api

I have a variable "mail" inside "onPlayerReady" in which i have email adress, i want to call this variable inside "onPlayerStateChange" so that i can pass the value to 'input.php' page to save it into database.

```
$(function(){
  var youtubePlayer;
  var myWindow = window;
  var vid_id='ha48nSKLLh8';
  onYouTubeIframeAPIReady = function(){
   youtubePlayer = new YT.Player('youtube', {
     height: '390',
     width: '640',
     videoId: vid_id,
     events: {
       'onReady': onPlayerReady,
       'onStateChange': onPlayerStateChange
     }
   });
   }

  onPlayerReady = function(event) {
   event.target.pauseVideo();
   var mail=prompt('email:'); //this is the variable mail i am talking about i want the value if this variable inside onPlayerStateChange


   };


  onPlayerStateChange = function(event) {

   if (event.data == 1) {
       var tm = youtubePlayer.getCurrentTime();
       var st = youtubePlayer.getPlayerState();
       //$("#status1").text(tm);    


       $("#status1").text(st);
       $.ajax({
        type: 'POST',
        url: 'input.php',
        data:{ tm: tm, vid_id: vid_id,mail:mail},   
        success:function(html){
           alert(done);

        }
    });

       //$("#status1").text(tm);

     $("#status").text("Playing!");
     myWindow.focus();
     myWindow.onblur = function() {
       $("#status").text("You went away!");
       youtubePlayer.stopVideo();
     };
   }

  };

  youtubeplayer.bind('play',function(){
      youtubeplayer.time(60);
      return this.unbind;
  });
})
```

please help me with this or suggest me if there is any other way to save the email entered at "onPlayerReady".
Thanks in advance!

Comment: You can achieve this the same way as you achieved youtubePlayer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would suggest to declare the `mail` variable inside your closure and NOT as s global if not necessary i.e:

```
$(function(){
    var mail = null; // not a global, but available in the entire function scope.
    var youtubePlayer;
    var myWindow = window;
    ...
```

The nuance is that now NO other code can potentially override the `mail` variable (or vice versa), therefore no naming collisions.
It's best practice to avoid globals as much a possible in javascript.

Only make sure to NOT redefine you `mail` variable in `onPlayerReady()`:

```
onPlayerReady = function(event) {
   event.target.pauseVideo();
   mail = prompt('email:'); // Only store the prompt input (i.e no var).
};
```

And this way you can still access the `mail` variable in you ajax request without the downsides mentioned above.

Also for reference check this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10525582/why-are-global-variables-considered-bad-practice-javascript).

Answer (score 0):

If you declare the `mail` variable outside the `$(function()`, it will be a [global variable](https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/bzt2dkta(v=vs.94).aspx) and accessible by all your Javascript code. E.g.

```
var mail = "";
$(function(){
    ...

    onPlayerReady = function(event) {
        event.target.pauseVideo();
        mail=prompt('email:'); // remove the var here
    };
```

In fact, as @nikhil pointed out, you can even put it inside the outer `function()` (as long as it is outside the `onPlayerReady` function).

Comment: i want to use seekto() to in the same code to start the video after sometime! Can anyone help me with this?

Comment: If you *have* a new question, please *post* a new question.