# How to send data from controller to controller

Tags: json, angularjs, scope

I want to send data from one controller to another controller in angularjs without using

```
$scope.$broadcast
```

Comment: without service is it possible or not

Comment: Instead of a service you could use a factory :)

Comment: Service or factory method is correct way.Or You can store the data in localStorage or cookies.

Comment: local storage data not secured ok thankyou

Answer (score 0):

Use scope if controllers are nested. Use required derictive controller

Answer (score 0):

You should use a service or a factory but it is also possible to store data in $rootScope.

This is not advisable as root scope is a global variable and comes with its own set of problems [here is an explanation why](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10525582/why-are-global-variables-considered-bad-practice-javascript), but it might be just what you need if your testing something out.

In coding "if something's worth doing its worth doing right, right?" So I would advise building a factory in your Services.js file and then calling your factory in the controllers you want it accessible in.