# TypeScript Index Signature of object type implicitly has type any

Tags: typescript

I am trying to attach property on window object. Here is my code for that.

```
 cbid:string ='someValue';
 window[cbid] = (meta: any) => {
         tempThis.meta = meta;
         window[cbid] = undefined;
         var e = document.getElementById(cbid);
         e.parentNode.removeChild(e);
         if (meta.errorDetails) {
             return;
         }
     };
```

Compiler starts throwing the following **error.**

**TypeScript Index Signature of object type implicitly has type any**

Can someone tell me where I am doing the mistake?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A quick fix would be to allow anything to be assigned to the window object. You can do that by writing...

```
interface Window {
    [propName: string]: any;
}
```

...somewhere in your code.

Or you could compile with `--suppressImplicitAnyIndexErrors` to disable implicit any errors when assigning to an index on any object.

I wouldn't recommend either of these options though. Ideally it's best [not to assign to window](https://stackoverflow.com/q/10525582/188246), but if you really want to then you should probably do everything on one property then define an index signature that matches what's being assigned to it:

```
// define it on Window
interface Window {
    cbids: { [cbid: string]: (meta: any) => void; }
}

// initialize it somewhere
window.cbids = {};

// then when adding a property
// (note: hopefully cbid is scoped to maintain it's value within the function)
var cbid = 'someValue';
window.cbids[cbid] = (meta: any) => {
    tempThis.meta = meta;
    delete window.cbids[cbid]; // use delete here
    var e = document.getElementById(cbid);
    e.parentNode.removeChild(e);

    if (meta.errorDetails) {
        return;
    }
};
```