# How to access an object value in TypeScript using string index

Tags: javascript, typescript

I have an object and I want to access the object value using a string index, but when I try to do that in TypeScript, I'm getting errors.

```
// Declared Globally
const Orientation = {
    value: () => 0,
    'next_value': () => someFunction.anotherFunction.sqrt(),
};

// _textValue type declared 
_textValue : string;

// Declared inside constructor
this._textValue = 'next_value';

// value used inside a function
_getValue(){
    const newValue = Orientation[this._textValue]();
 }
```

And where I use `Orientation[this._textValue]();`, I'm getting the error as:

> Element implicitly has an 'any' type because expression of type 'any' can't be used to index type '{ value: () => number; 'next_value': () => number; }'.ts(7053)

Any idea on how to resolve this?

Comment: I think you can extend interface to be able to index using string like; `interface A { [b: string]: string }` You can look over to this [playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/#code/JYOwLgpgTgZghgYwgAgCrIN4Chm+QbTgC5kBnMKUAcwF0TzKQqsBfLLBAexHOQRPQBeTDjwAiOGJJiAFhAA28zmIA0o3ACNpkcqvV9pcDQjGt2XHp3kQAdEqoAKBPgliaASgDcHbqSu37JxcNNy8fS2s7TkcEGwQvIA)

Comment: Can you provide a reference?

Comment: check here; https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/interfaces.html and search for index signatures

Comment: Does this answer your question? [TypeScript Index Signature of object type implicitly has type any](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33350313/typescript-index-signature-of-object-type-implicitly-has-type-any)

Comment: Also, if you know `_textValue` will always be a key of `Orientation` you can use `_textValue: keyof typeof Orientation`.

Comment: What about the interface for the arrow function?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

main.ts

```js
export {}

interface IDictionary {
    [index: string]: string;
}
var params = {} as IDictionary;

//array with string index 
params = {a: "Bhavesh",b: "Bond", c: "Urmil"};

//get array data using string index
var getData = params['b']; // output: Bond
var getData = params['B']; // output: undefined

console.log(getData);
```

I think your problem will be solved in the above example code. thank you..!

Comment: Very nice. You can also write `var params: IDictionary = {};` which is cleaner as no assertion is actually necessary here.

Answer (score -1):

This is the first link google shows me for this problem.
The easiest way i found is converting the object to any first:

```
const newValue = (Orientation as any)[this._textValue]();
```

And that's pretty much it.