# how to get a value from anchor tag and use it for another function

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a very simple problem but I can't figure it out,
Im newbie with regards to this.

I have a following functions where user will click a button of something he/she wants to search, then when he/she chose and clicks something around the choices,he/she will click a search button to search.

Here is my code for getting the value from anchor tags, the choices is wrapped up in anchor tags.

```
$(document).on('click' , '#area_id_1' , function(){ 
var getText1 = $("#area_id_1").text();
alert(getText1); return false; });



$(document).on('click' , '#area_id_2' , function(){ 
var getText1 = $("#area_id_2").text();
alert(getText1);
return false; 
});



$(document).on('click' , '#area_id_3' , function(){ 
var getText1 = $("#area_id_3").text();
alert(getText1); return false;});



$(document).on('click' , '#area_id_4' , function(){ 
var getText1 = $("#area_id_4").text();
alert(getText1);
return false;
});



$(document).on('click' , '#area_id_5' , function(){ 
var getText1 = $("#area_id_5").text();
alert(getText1); return false;});



$(document).on('click' , '#area_id_6' , function(){ 
var getText1 = $("#area_id_6").text();
alert(getText1); return false;  });



$(document).on('click' , '#area_id_7' , function(){ 
var getText1 = $("#area_id_7").text();
alert(getText1); return false;  });


$(document).on('click' , '#area_id_8' , function(){ 
var getText1 = $("#area_id_8").text();
alert(getText1); return false; });
```

and here is my function for search button
//button for search function

```
$(document).on('click', '#btnSearch', function() {
```

}

The question is, how will I be able to store the value that I got from the anchor tags so I can use it when I click the btnSearch function?

Comment: declare the variable in the global scope

Comment: you need to use global variable

Comment: Also you can use `$(this).text();` instead of `$("#area_id_1").text();`, `$("#area_id_1").text();` etc..

Comment: I did all of your suggestions and it worked, thanks guys!
it made my code more clean.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all **define your variable getText1 global** as below.

```
var getText1;

$(document).on('click' , '#area_id_1' , function(){ 
    getText1 = $(this).text();
    return false; 
});

...(rest of your code)
// and you will get the variable in below function

$(document).on('click', '#btnSearch', function() {
    alert(getText1); // you can check here if it is empty or not
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to use global variable or window variable .. Refer this 
[Click](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5786899/5336818)  .. I will mention some examples

```
<script>
var yourGlobalVariable;   // this is global variable
function foo() {
    // ...
}
</script>


<script>
function foo() {
    window.yourGlobalVariable = ...;   // this is window variable you can use
}
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

First of all, I don't recommend using global variable.
[Global variable is bad practice](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10525582/why-are-global-variables-considered-bad-practice-javascript%20%22)

If you don't want to use global variable.
You can set the value on the btnSearch element.
Use jQuery.fn.data function, you can store value to element with specific key string.
https://api.jquery.com/data/

And you can use multiple selector. To attach same event handler function to multiple elements once.
https://api.jquery.com/multiple-selector/

```
// You can use same handler function on multiple element once.
// You don't have to declare same function each time.
$('#area_id_1, #area_id_2, #area_id_3, #area_id_4' +
', #area_id_5, #area_id_6, #area_id_7, #area_id_8').on('click', function() {
    var text = $(this).text();
    // Set value at $('#btnSearch') with "text" key
    $('#btnSearch').data("text", text);
    alert(text);
    return false;
});

$(document).on('click', '#btnSearch', function() {
    var text = $(this).data("text"); // You can get the value like this
}
```