# How to access javascript variable's function

Tags: javascript, html

I have a javascript file with this code:

```
(function () {

    var cookieconsent = {

        dismiss: function (evt) {
          evt.preventDefault && evt.preventDefault();
          evt.returnValue = false;
          this.setDismissedCookie();
          this.container.removeChild(this.element);
        },

        setDismissedCookie: function () {
          Util.setCookie(DISMISSED_COOKIE, 'yes', this.options.expiryDays, this.options.domain, this.options.path);
        }

    };

})();
```

How can I access the function "dismiss" from, let's say, the console of the browser or an a href link on the page?

This is the source of the file: [Cookie Consent - GitHub](https://github.com/silktide/cookieconsent2/blob/master/cookieconsent.js)

Thanks!

Comment: cookieconsent.dismiss

Comment: You cannot. The variable `cookieconsent` is local to the anonymous function in which it is declared. It is not visible or accessible outside that function (at least, not according to the code you posted).

Comment: Is this code you can modify or code that is included on a page you're trying to modify/use?

Comment: Also, if you *really* "have a JavaScript file with this code", understand that your code does absolutely nothing.

Comment: @IMTheNachoMan this code is a JS file included in my page. I can edit it, but I would need to access that function from the code in my HTML page

Comment: Then why did you put it in an anonymous function like that?

Comment: @Pointy, I am able to trigger that function when clicking on a button and I would like to trigger the same event when clicking on the page. This function dismiss a popup basically.

Comment: Again, the code you posted *does not do anything at all*. If you're going to ask a question, it's important that the *real* code be posted.

Comment: @IMTheNachoMan I haven't written that function, it's the javascript included in my page.

Comment: This is the source of the file: https://github.com/silktide/cookieconsent2/blob/master/cookieconsent.js

Comment: var cookieconsent should be then passed as a parameter

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A variable is accessible in its scope only. So if you do

```js
function helloWorld(){
  var test = "Test";
}
```

`test` is only available inside `helloWorld`.

When you do

```js
var test = "test";

function notify(){
  console.log(test);
}
```

`test` will be accessible since it is defined in higher scope.

When you do same thing in a JS file, since this variable is not enclosed inside a function, it becomes a part of global scope (`window`) and hence they are available everywhere.

If you wish to make a variable global, you can use `window.variableName` and access it.

**Note:** Its a bad practice to pollute global scope. Refer [Why are global variables considered bad practice?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10525582/why-are-global-variables-considered-bad-practice)

Also if you wish to bind a function on HTML element, try

```js
document.getElementById("elementId").addEventListener("click", cookieconsent.dismiss)
```

About accessing it on console, try logging it in console and then you can save logged object in a global object using chrome debugger and test it.

Answer (score 2):

You cannot because the variable is defined in the scope of the anonymous function that is called when this script is executed. You can however alter the code the make the variable accessible like this:

```
(function (global) {

    global.cookieconsent = {

        ...

    };

})(this);
```

Answer (score 1):

Just remove the `var` keyword and access the function as `cookieconsent.dismiss` from the global context. See the @Pointy's comment to your question.

Answer (score 1):

I suppose you could try a few different approaches:

```
(function () {

    window.cookieconsent = {

        dismiss: function (evt) {
          evt.preventDefault && evt.preventDefault();
          evt.returnValue = false;
          this.setDismissedCookie();
          this.container.removeChild(this.element);
        },

        setDismissedCookie: function () {
          Util.setCookie(DISMISSED_COOKIE, 'yes', this.options.expiryDays, this.options.domain, this.options.path);
        }

    };

})();

cookieconsent.dismiss();
```

Comment: Do refer following post before using global scope: [Why are global variables considered bad practice?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10525582/why-are-global-variables-considered-bad-practice)

Comment: I will point out this is not very "good" code. If you can shed more light on what you're doing/trying-to-do then there might be a "better" solution.