# charts labels and data with php arrays

Tags: javascript, php, html, chart.js

When I pass the array as an argument to the chart it stops showing on the web 
  page.

```
<?php
$f = fopen("C:\wamp64\www\dashb\CSV\salespermonthdollars.csv", "r");
$labels = array();
$data = array();
$loopCounter = 0;
while (($line = fgetcsv($f)) !== false) {
  if($loopCounter == 0){
    // this if is to skip the first row or the columns
  } else {
    array_push($labels,$line[0]);
    array_push($data,$line[1]);
  }
  $loopCounter = $loopCounter + 1; 
}
fclose($f); 
?>
```

So above I read the csv file that I save from my query result and try to plot it on a chart:

```
<canvas id="myChart2">
<script>
$array3 = [1,2,3,4,5,5,41]; 
$array4 = [1,2,3,4,5,5,41];
var ctx = document.getElementById('myChart2').getContext('2d');
var myBarChart = new Chart(ctx, {
    type: 'bar',
    data: {
    labels: $array3, //when i change this to $labels doesn't work same for4
    datasets: [{
      label: 'label',
      data: $array4,
      backgroundColor: "rgba(100,255,51,0.4)"
     }]
  }
    });
</script>
</canvas>
```

Mainly I am displaying query result on a chart. I execute, save to csv and read
from there.

Any suggestions for improvement in the approach are welcome, somehow I feel it could be done easier than this.

Comment: No errors or what so ever btw. Feels like a versioning issue or maybe its just a bad approach

Answer (score 1):

It is because `$labels` is not Javascript, but PHP variable. So what you need to do is to decode it in php part of your code:

```
...
fclose($f); 
$labels = json_decode($label);
```

And in Javascript part:

```
var labels = JSON.parse("<?php echo $labels; ?>");
```

As part of suggestions of improvement goes, [you should not declare global variables](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10525582/why-are-global-variables-considered-bad-practice). So what you are doing here:

```
$array3 = [1,2,3,4,5,5,41]; 
$array4 = [1,2,3,4,5,5,41];
```

Should be:

```
var array3 = [1,2,3,4,5,5,41]; 
var array4 = [1,2,3,4,5,5,41];
```

I removed `$` - dollars from their names, because [it's common practice to declare jQuery wrapper variables](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/205853/why-would-a-javascript-variable-start-with-a-dollar-sign) and those are obviously not. Also, by `$` prefix to their names, I can only guess that what you wanted to do was to declare php variables inside your `<script>` and then use them directly, but **it is not possible**, because first of all, you are missing `<?php` part, and second - they would be only saved in the memory by just declaring them.

Comment: So perhaps i should just do this completely with javascript ? is there an advantage to using php in this context ? I only did coz it was the first thing i found to execute the queries and just took it from there.

Comment: You will not be able to do that without using server side language as for example php, because you are not able to read file on the client side and you wont be able to create chart on server side. Using both is a key, to that, just make sure you do it right.

Comment: Thanks. Working fine now, i will now add some buttons to update queries when needed. Wanted to use some of those open source dashboard frameworks but they really looked like an overkill so i just take examples from them.