# How to access functions defined in ES6 module in a browser's JavaScript console?

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6, es6-modules

I have a function that is defined in an ES6 module (`sender.js`) as follows:

```
function send() {
   // do stuff
}
export {send};
```

This module is then used in the application's main JavaScript file `app.js` as follows:

```
import {send} from "./sender"
```

The `send` function is available in the `app.js` file, however **it is not** in Firefox's Javascript console:

```
> send
ReferenceError: send is not defined
```

How can I import the `send` function in the JavaScript console?

Comment: ES 6 modules are not supported by any browser, so I assume that you're using Babel, right?

Comment: yes, I am using Babel

Comment: Are you using any bundler, like webpack, Browserify or Rollup?

Answer (score 28, accepted):

You can set the specific function as global by assigning it to the global object –
in browsers it's `window`.

```
// To make one function available in the browser:
import { send } from "./sender.js"; // Might omit `.js` if using a bundler.
window.send = send;

// To make all functions available:
import * as sender from "./sender.js";
window.sender = sender;

// In the browser console:
window.sender.send()
```

Note that while it might be useful in debugging, you shouldn't use that in production code – see [Why are global variables considered bad practice?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/10525582/3853934)

Comment: What I'm wondering is, since `send` is declared in a file, not being wrapped in any function, shouldn't that be a global? Is this specific to files loaded via `import`?

Comment: @IonicăBizău I think it depends on what bundler the OP is using. This behavior seems logical to me, because there's no need for an app to expose any functions. For example, [Rollup complies the code in question to an empty file](https://goo.gl​/PM4zOq).

Comment: @IonicăBizău Yes, it is specific to them. The files that are loaded with import are modules, and modules have their own scopes. That's the purpose of modules - being modular and not pollute global scope.

Comment: @estus That sounds very good! Yes, I was asking from the native perspective, without bundlers. Thanks!

Comment: @MichałPerłakowski is there a way to access all functions of a module in the browser

Comment: @MAS Added details on how to import all functions from a module.