# Is it possible to use a JavaScript module from "normal" javascript (debugger)?

Tags: javascript, html

I've tried to read up on JavaScript modules, but I'm still not clear on one thing: assume the following minimal HTML example:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8"/>
  <title>Test</title>

  <script type="module">
  export function hello() {
    console.log("hello");
  }
  </script>

</head>
<body>
</body>
</html>
```

Let's say I load this in my browser via `file:///C:/tmp/test.html` - it is the `file://` protocol, yes, but there is no .js file being loaded, as the script is embedded, so CORS should not be a problem (and I don't get a Console JavaScript error either).

So let's say, I load this page in Firefox 115, and I open the Console/JavaScript Debugger. No "hello" is accessible by default:

```
>> hello
Uncaught ReferenceError: hello is not defined
    <anonymous> debugger eval code:1
```

... and I cannot "import" or "require":

```
>> import { hello }
Uncaught SyntaxError: import declarations may only appear at top level of a module

>> require("hello")
Uncaught ReferenceError: require is not defined
    <anonymous> debugger eval code:1
```

(maybe `require` needs a library, but as you can tell, I'm not really a JavaScript guru)

So - is there *anything* I can do with my `<script type="module">` from "normal" JavaScript (that is, either `<script>` which is not `type="module"` - or direct commands in JavaScript Debugger/Console), without explicitly saying `window.hello = hello;` at the end of the module code?

Comment: You're not too far, but not exactly right. I'd suggest reading https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Modules

Comment: What are you trying to do? Your script is loaded into the browser; there's nowhere to `export` to. You can create a global value to expose symbols from the script to other scripts on the page.

Comment: Generally you make an inline script a module because you want to **import** something, not export. Recall that `import` needs a "from"; there's no "from" for a script like yours.

Comment: Related answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/44355041/188331

Comment: Thanks all: "I'd suggest reading" - did that, but it mostly deals with import/export to/from modules, not with interaction of "normal" script and module; "What are you trying to do?" understand if there is an interaction between "normal" script and module or not. Just an explicit statement "No - a normal script cannot interact with a module, unless the module exports global (window.) variables" would be good enough for me (if it is indeed true).

Answer (score 0):

It's a losing battle.

- You can inline a script of type `module` in HTML successfully and create exports. Well you can go through the motions and `console.log` that the script ran without error.
- You can inline a script of type `module` and execute an `import` statement, but at this point the fun begins:

  - Attempts to import an inline module that exports something fail because the inline module has no [`module-name`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/import#syntax) associated with it.
  - Ok, so put code for the exporting module code in a file called `test-module.js`, in the same folder as the HTML file and try importing it in a script inlined in the HTML

  ```
      <script type="module">
      import {x} from "./test-module.js";
      console.log("x from xmodule = ", x);
      </script>
  ```

  At this point the module loader *does* attempt to load the file using CORS. And generates the following error:

  > ❌ Cross-Origin Request Blocked: The Same Origin Policy disallows reading the remote resource at file:///html-path/test-module.js. (Reason: CORS request not http).

  An explanation of the error reason is given on [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/CORS/Errors/CORSRequestNotHttp?utm_source=devtools&utm_medium=firefox-cors-errors&utm_campaign=default) but essentially CORS does not support any protocols other than `http://` or `https://`.

Battle lost I believe.

The work around commonly suggested is to install a `localhost` server to run and load all module testing code from, which can be frustrating in use and unsuited for projects that are intended to work off-line. I am unaware of any attempts to provide support for  ES6 module access when using the `file://` protocol. Not even the ability to give an inline script of type `module` a `module-name` attribute.