# Alternatives to callbacks / promises or global variables in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, callback, promise, global-variables

My question is about a smarter solution / alternative to callbacks / promises or global variables.

**Situation:** I have a program which is event-driven. I know that Function `A` will calculate a value `v` that I will need at a later point. `A` will be called right at the start of the program. Function `B` may or may not be triggered by an event at a later point.

**Question:** How can I pass `v` from `A` to `B` without using a callback, since `B` should not be called by `A` but rather by some event. How can I avoid using a global Variable ([since they are bad](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10525582/why-are-global-variables-considered-bad-practice))?

Comment: If `B` isn't in the scope of `A`, then global variables are generally the only option. They shouldn't be used excessively, but sometimes they're the right thing.

Comment: @Barmar Thank you very much for your comment. I was afraid that was the answer to this question. But let`s wait. Maybe there are other suggestions of things we did not consider.

Comment: Is `A` sync or async? Can the caller of `A` simply inject the value into `B` somehow, e.g. when setting up `B` as an event handler? Is there anything shared between the two, e.g. they're both members of the same class?

Comment: Note that the variable doesn't have to be fully global, you can combine `A` and `B` into a local scope that they share. Or you can use objects to package variables.

Comment: @deceze They are not member of the shared classes and could be at two  completely different parts of the application. `A` may or may not be async. Could be pls explain, why that is important? `B` will always be called after `A`, no matter if `A` is async or not

Answer (score 1):

You may use a closure. I mean `val` is in the scope of Function A, and the event listener can be "registered" from within function A. Since `val` will be under closure it can still be accessed by the event listener such as;

```js
function A(n) {
  var but = document.getElementById("me"),
      res = document.getElementById("result"),
      val = Math.floor(Math.random() * n) + 1;
  but.addEventListener("click", function(e) {
                                  res.textContent = val;
                                  res.style.backgroundColor = '#' + Math.random().toString(16).substr(-6);
                                });
}

A(100);
```

```html
<script src="index.js" defer></script>
<label for="me">To get the ready value please click</label>
<button id="me">me..!</button>
<p id="result"></p>
```

As you see the value is calculated synchronously only once at the beginning but the background color is being calculated every time.

Comment: This is an interesting idea. Thank you

Answer (score 0):

The best alternative is to have a closed scope with a variable that the two functions can share:

```js
var B, A;
(function() {
  //Local scope variable that is only accessible in this scope
  var v = 1;
  //Define function B
  B = function B() {
    console.log("v is", v);
  };
  //Define function A
  A = function A() {
    setTimeout(function() {
      v++;
      console.log("A has changed the value of v");
    }, 1000);
  };
})();
A(); // --> Start A, which modifies the local variable v
B(); // --> Start B before A has finished. B logs current value of local variable v
setTimeout(function() {
  B(); // --> Start B after A has finished. B logs current value of local variable v
}, 2000);
```

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer, Emil. Good idea, but only works if `A` and `B` are in the same file. They might be at 2 completely different parts of the program, though. 

Btw: You can do this without using a self calling function, [if you are using `let`](https://developer.mozilla.org/de/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/let), since this is not using function scope.