# Is it possible to share global declarations in TypeScript?

Tags: typescript

I usually have some server-side variables that I put into the global scope, so that I can access them from anywhere in my client side TypeScript code, e.g.:

Server in .cshtml:

```
<script>
  const RazorGlobals = {
    apiBaseUrl: '@Model.ApiBaseUrl'
  }
</script>
```

Client code:

```
declare const RazorGlobals: {
  apiBaseUrl: string
}

fetch(RazorGlobals.apiBaseUrl + '/myResource').then(doStuff)
```

At the moment I have to repeat the `declare const RazorGlobals...` part at the top of every file where I need to use it. I am looking for a way to define this declaration in a single place, something like this pseudocode:

globals.d.ts:

```
export declare const RazorGlobals: {
  apiBaseUrl: string
}
```

file1.ts:

```
import './globals'

fetch(RazorGlobals.apiBaseUrl + '/myResource').then(doStuff)
```

file2.ts:

```
import './globals'

fetch(RazorGlobals.apiBaseUrl + '/myOtherResource').then(doOtherStuff)
```

Is there a way to achieve something like this?

Comment: put the d.ts file somewhere where both applications can access?

Comment: Yeah that's implied sorry. Updated the code to clarify my intention.

Comment: he wants to add typings for a variable that is defined in the global context. Your solution would just make a variable in a module named globals. His aproach is correct he just needs to figure out how to get the compiler to include his file as well as a definition.

Comment: if the globals d.ts file is in the same folder as your project. just remove the `export` and the import statement. tsc should pick it up automatically. That being said @gilamran does have a point you should probably not just asume it will exist but actually make it part of your applications config.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you want to declare the presence of a global variable that is available everywhere all you need to is have a .d.ts file with the declaration in it.

```js
// globals.d.ts
declare const RazorGlobals: {
  apiBaseUrl: string
}
```

No imports should be necessary.

Comment: This answers the exact question I was asking, so I'll mark it as the answer. With that said, I probably will do something like @gilamran suggests instead, seems like a safer approach :)

Comment: it sure does. :)

Answer (score 3):

First, don't assume global variables, [there are many reasons for that](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10525582/why-are-global-variables-considered-bad-practice).

You can have a module in the client that exposes these types, this module should take the global variable and expose it.

For example

**config.ts**

```
import { IAppConfig } from '../shared/AppConfig';
export const APP_CONFIG: IAppConfig = (window as any).RazorGlobals;
```

**component.ts**

```
import { APP_CONFIG } from './config';
console.log(APP_CONFIG.apiBaseUrl);
```

As for sharing types, you should have a `shared` folder between the client and server, and all the types should be there, in this example `AppConfig.d.ts`

Compiling the client AND the server with the same `tsconfig.json` is very problematic. I have a [medium post](https://medium.com/front-end-hacking/client-server-and-shared-code-846097c5260e) on that, and an open source [starter-kit](https://github.com/gilamran/fullstack-typescript).