# i keep getting this error "Uncaught TypeError: name.push is not a function at <anonymous>:10:7"

Tags: javascript

```js
var name = [];
var input = prompt("what u want?");

while (input !== "quit"){
 if (input === "list"){
  console.log(name);
 }
 else if(input === "new"){
  var hold = prompt("Enter");
  name.push(hold);
 }
 input = prompt("What u want?");
 }
 console.log("u quit");
```

So here is the situation,
i am trying to run this **TODO_APP**  and i think i did everything right,
but i am keep on getting error at **push section** "name.push is not a function" tell me where i am doing wrong..

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**You can't change the type of `name`** as it is already **defined globally**. Use a different variable - `name1`.

```js
var name1 = [];
var input = prompt("what u want?");

while (input !== "quit") {
  if (input === "list") {
    console.log(name1);
  } else if (input === "new") {
    var hold = prompt("Enter");
    name1.push(hold);
  }
  input = prompt("What u want?");
}
console.log("u quit");
```

Answer (score 0):

Issue in your code is that, any variable that is defined outside any function is added in global scope(`window`). Now `window` already has a property called name and you cannot override it. Hence it throws error.

**Solution:**

- Change the variable name
- Wrap code in a IIFE so you do not bleed to global scope. Following is a sample of it.

```js
(function() {
  var name = [];
  var input = prompt("what u want?");

  while (input !== "quit") {
    if (input === "list") {
      console.log(name);
    } else if (input === "new") {
      var hold = prompt("Enter");
      name.push(hold);
    }
    input = prompt("What u want?");
  }
  console.log("u quit", name);
})()
```

---

Note: its a bad practice to bleed to global scope.

#### References:

- [Why are global variables considered bad practice?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10525582/why-are-global-variables-considered-bad-practice)
- [Window.name property](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/API/Window/name)