# Javascript array random choosing issue

Tags: javascript, arrays

```
var eg = "one"
var eg2 = "two"
var eg3 = "three"

function randomchoose() {
    var rand = ["eg", "eg2", "eg3"];
    var act = [eg, eg2, eg3];
    choose = rand[Math.floor(Math.random()*rand.length)]
    chosen = act[choose]
    return [chosen, choose];
}
```

my issue with this is that I don't know how to make "chosen" be the variable that was randomly chosen.

basically, if it rolls eg, i want chosen to be "one" and same goes for others

------EDIT------
I forgot to specify, i need it to return the variable name as "choose" and the actual value as "chosen"

Comment: What exactly do you plan to do with the returned variable name? Sounds like you should create an object instead of use multiple variables

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You just need to store the random number you get and pass with the array when you need it. Here is snippet

Updated as per your question

```js
var eg = "one"
var eg2 = "two"
var eg3 = "three"

function randomchoose() {
    var rand = ["eg", "eg2", "eg3"];
    var act = [eg, eg2, eg3];
    randomNumber = Math.floor(Math.random()*rand.length)
    chosen = act[randomNumber]
    choose = rand[randomNumber]
    return [chosen, choose];
}
console.log(randomchoose())
```

Comment: I am laughing now, who downvoted this and why? Well Happy to help you :)

Answer (score 2):

As I understood, you want to return field name and field value, which were randomly chosen.
Here's a snippet:

```js
var eg = "one"
var eg2 = "two"
var eg3 = "three"

function choseRandom() {
  var rand = ["eg", "eg2", "eg3"];
  var act = [eg, eg2, eg3];
  var chosenIndex = Math.floor(Math.random()*rand.length);
  var fieldName = rand[chosenIndex]
  var fieldValue = act[chosenIndex]
  return [fieldName, fieldValue];
}

console.log(choseRandom());
console.log(choseRandom());
console.log(choseRandom());
```

Comment: What exactly doesn't work in my snippet for you? I'll update the answer if something's off, but it should work correctly.

Comment: Ah, okay. Also I've updated the `choose` and `chosen` variables, to better reflect the purpose and made them local, instead of global ([Why are global variables considered bad practice?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10525582/why-are-global-variables-considered-bad-practice)). Also you might want to change the return value from array to object, but it really depends on your case I guess.

Comment: in my case i'd need arrays, this little code is later used and requires arrays...very specific i know haha, anyway thanks a lot for the help!

Answer (score 1):

Use an object instead of multiple variables to store the values

```js
var data = {
  eg: "one",
  eg2: "two",
  eg3: "three"
}

function randomchoose() {
  var rand = ["eg", "eg2", "eg3"];

  choose = rand[Math.floor(Math.random() * rand.length)]
  chosen = data[choose]
  return [chosen, choose];
}

console.log(randomchoose())
```

Answer (score 0):

**chosen = act[rand.indexOf(choose)]**

Comment: Can you give a more elaborate answer. You can post an example of the fixed code, for example.