# Exception in template helper: TypeError: Cannot read property 'mergedSchema' of undefined

Tags: meteor, meteor-autoform, simpl-schema

I am new in meteor. I am using simple schema  for quickForm and got this error.
Exception in template helper: TypeError: Cannot read property 'mergedSchema' of undefined

**main.html**

```
<template name="hello">
  <button>Click Me</button>
  <p>You've pressed the button {{counter}} times.</p>
  {{> quickForm collection="Books" id="bookUpdateForm" type="insert"}}    

</template>
```

**main.js**

```
import './hello.html';    
import { Books } from '../../../api/links/books.js';

 Template.hello.onCreated(function () {
     Meteor.subscribe('books');
 });
```

**Collection JS**

```
import SimpleSchema from 'simpl-schema';
export const Books = new Mongo.Collection("books");
const Book = new SimpleSchema({
title: {
    type: String,
    label: "Title",
    max: 200
},
author: {
    type: String,
    label: "Author"
},
copies: {
    type: SimpleSchema.Integer,
    label: "Number of copies",
    min: 0
},
lastCheckedOut: {
    type: Date,
    label: "Last date this book was checked out",
    optional: true
},
summary: {
    type: String,
    label: "Brief summary",
    optional: true,
    max: 1000
}
```

});

Books.attachSchema(Book);

Comment: Please add some code, otherwise it is hard to tell what the source of the error could be. For example this could be a wrong import, a missing or wrong instantiation of the schema, the schema object is missing and so on.

Comment: I have added the code please look into this.  sometime I get this issue **Exception in template helper: Error: Books is not in the window scope** I try out this solution **https://github.com/aldeed/meteor-autoform/issues/1449** Now I got this one **Exception in template helper: TypeError: Cannot read property 'mergedSchema' of undefined**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is a typo that causes a follow up error. You collection is namen `"books"` but you pass `"Books"` to your `quickForm`. Because `AutoForm` cannot find any collection named `"Books"` in global scope it will throw an error.

This approach also assumes `Books` to be in window scope.

If you are new to JS, then you may first read about scopes and window scope:

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/Scope

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window

[Why are global variables considered bad practice?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10525582/why-are-global-variables-considered-bad-practice)

#### Less error prone pattern

An alternative approach would be to import `Books` to your template (as you have already done) and provide it to `quickForm` **via a Template helper**:

**main.html**

```js
<template name="hello">
  {{> quickForm collection=getCollection id="bookUpdateForm" type="insert"}}    
</template>
```

Note `getCollection` which is basically calling a helper you define in your Template helpers section:

**main.js**

```js
import './hello.html';    
import { Books } from '../../../api/links/books.js';

Template.hello.onCreated(function () {
    Meteor.subscribe('books');
});

Template.hello.helpers({
    getCollection() {
      return Books;
    }
});
```

By doing so you have a) avoided window (global) scope and b) avoided errors due to spelling errors, because you pass the reference to the collection directly to the quickForm.

**Collection JS**

```js
import SimpleSchema from 'simpl-schema';
export const Books = new Mongo.Collection("books");
const Book = new SimpleSchema({
    title: {
        type: String,
        label: "Title",
        max: 200
    },
    author: {
        type: String,
        label: "Author"
    },
    copies: {
        type: SimpleSchema.Integer,
        label: "Number of copies",
        min: 0
    },
    lastCheckedOut: {
        type: Date,
        label: "Last date this book was checked out",
        optional: true
    },
    summary: {
        type: String,
        label: "Brief summary",
        optional: true,
        max: 1000
    }
});

Books.attachSchema(Book);
```

Comment: Thanks a lot. It works. and also I have to downgrade to my simpl-schema package 1.5.0. to 1.4.0.

Comment: And thanks a lot for the scope link. It really help.