# Сounting the number of comparisons and permutations in heapsort

Tags: python, function, sorting, heapsort

I'm trying to count the number of comparisons and swaps in heapsort algorithm (num_comps and num_swaps accordingly):

```
import numpy as np
import timeit


def heapify(arr, len_arr, i):
    num_swaps = 0
    num_comps = 0
    maxima = i
    l = 2 * i + 1
    r = 2 * i + 2
    num_comps += 1
    if l < len_arr and arr[i] < arr[l]:
        maxima = l
    num_comps += 1
    if r < len_arr and arr[maxima] < arr[r]:
        maxima = r
    if maxima != i:
        num_swaps += 1
        arr[i], arr[maxima] = arr[maxima], arr[i]
        heapify(arr, len_arr, maxima)
    return num_swaps, num_comps


def heap_sort(arr):
    num_swaps = 0
    num_comps = 0
    len_arr = len(arr)
    for i in range(len_arr, -1, -1):
        heapify(arr, len_arr, i)
    for i in range(len_arr - 1, 0, -1):
        num_swaps += 1
        arr[i], arr[0] = arr[0], arr[i]
        heapify(arr, i, 0)
    return num_swaps, num_comps


flag = input("If you wanna randomize entered data, press 'Enter'. To enter manually press any other key: ")

if flag == '':
    arr = np.random.randint(-10000, 10000, 1000)
else:
    while True:
        try:
            arr = []
            for i in range(10):
                a = int(input(f'Enter {i + 1} element: '))
                arr.append(a)
            break
        except ValueError:
            print("Input an integer!")
print(f'Non-sorted array: \n {arr}')

num_comps, num_swaps = heap_sort(arr)

len_arr = len(arr)
print(f'Sorted array: \n {arr}')
print(num_comps, 'comparisons were executed')
print(num_swaps, 'swaps were executed ')
t = timeit.timeit('"-".join(str(n) for n in range(100))', number=10000)
print(f"Program was executed by {t} seconds")
```

My code works but display wrong values. I know that I'm doing something wrong but I can't understand what exactly. I'm just learning python functions so please show me the code examples. I would be grateful for any help.

UPD: I modified my code according to @Luke19 answer, but I still have wrong values (1000 numbers to sort, 1000 comparisons and 2 swaps).

Comment: Btw, if you found that my answer helped you solve your problem, it is common courtesy to mark it as accepted ;)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your `heapify` function returns two objects, so you should be using the same syntax you used for `heap_sort`*: `num_swaps, num_comps = heapify(...)`. If you don't do that, your `num_comps` variable will not be updated inside `heap_sort`.

UPDATE:

Note that using global variables is often not ideal. (You can find some discussion on that [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/484635/are-global-variables-bad) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10525582/why-are-global-variables-considered-bad-practice), for example.) Usually if there is a simple way around it, you should avoid them in order to have a less bug-prone code.

So, I'll provide you with a more detailed explanation of how to fix your code without using global variables:

First, notice that `num_swaps` and `num_comps` need to be updated every time you call `heapify`, even when calling `heapify` inside itself! However, in your original code those two counters were being reset to zero every time `heapify` was called. Therefore, in order for them to keep their current values, all you need to do is include them as arguments to `heapify`, then use the returned values to update the original ones.

Here's an example using your own code:

```py
#notice the change to the function's arguments
def heapify(arr, len_arr, i, num_swaps, num_comps):
    maxima = i

    #etc...

    #then every time you call heapify, pass your current num_swaps and     
    # num_comps then update them by setting them to the returned values:
    if maxima != i:
        num_swaps += 1
        arr[i], arr[maxima] = arr[maxima], arr[i]
        num_swaps, num_comps = heapify(arr, len_arr, maxima, num_swaps, num_comps) #notice the change to the line

    return num_swaps, num_comps
```

Because you're passing to `heapify` the current local values of `num_swaps` and `num_comps`, each time you do `num_swaps, num_comps = heapify(...,num_swaps, num_comps)` you will be updating your local values for those variables.

You should do the same thing for the calls to `heapify` inside your `heap_sort` function:

```
def heap_sort(arr):
    num_swaps = 0
    num_comps = 0
    len_arr = len(arr)
    for i in range(len_arr, -1, -1):
        num_swaps, num_comps = heapify(arr, len_arr, i, num_swaps, num_comps) #notice the change to this line

    #etc....

    return num_swaps, num_comps
```

Hope this helps! Let me know if it's clear.

Comment: I still cannot understand what I need to change. Can I ask you to show it in the piece of code?

Comment: or maybe you can explain me it in more detail?

Comment: I've updated my answer to give more detail and reflect the changes you made to your code. Specifically, I explain how to do it without using global variables, which is largely considered a good programming practice. Let me know if that's helpful!

Comment: Thanks for the useful advice. I hope it will improve my coding skills. That is nice experience for me.

Answer (score 0):

I fixed this problem and now I have such code:

```py
import numpy as np
import timeit


def heapify(arr, len_arr, i):
    global num_swaps
    global num_comps
    maxima = i
    l = 2 * i + 1
    r = 2 * i + 2
    num_comps += 1
    if l < len_arr and arr[i] < arr[l]:
        maxima = l
    num_comps += 1
    if r < len_arr and arr[maxima] < arr[r]:
        maxima = r
    if maxima != i:
        num_swaps += 1
        arr[i], arr[maxima] = arr[maxima], arr[i]
        heapify(arr, len_arr, maxima)



def heap_sort(arr):
    global num_swaps
    global num_comps
    len_arr = len(arr)
    heapify(arr, len_arr, 0)
    for i in range(len_arr, -1, -1):
        heapify(arr, len_arr, i)
    for i in range(len_arr - 1, 0, -1):
        num_swaps += 1
        arr[i], arr[0] = arr[0], arr[i]
        heapify(arr, i, 0)



flag = input("If you wanna randomize entered data, press 'Enter'. To enter manually press any other key: ")

if flag == '':
    arr = np.random.randint(-10000, 10000, 1000)
else:
    while True:
        try:
            arr = []
            for i in range(10):
                a = int(input(f'Enter {i + 1} element: '))
                arr.append(a)
            break
        except ValueError:
            print("Input an integer!")
print(f'Non-sorted array: \n {arr}')
num_swaps = 0
num_comps = 0
heap_sort(arr)

len_arr = len(arr)
print(f'Sorted array: \n {arr}')
print(num_comps, 'comparisons were executed')
print(num_swaps, 'swaps were executed ')
t = timeit.timeit('"-".join(str(n) for n in range(100))', number=10000)
print(f"Program was executed by {t} seconds")
```

I've just addeed global status to my in-function variables `num_swaps` and `num_comps` and set their zeroing directly before function call. This code works now and displays right sort performance indicators.