# How to use variable that is passed from exports.default function

Tags: javascript, node.js

I would like to find the best way to access function variables that are being used as parameters in other functions in another module. The `parsefile.js` is a Node.js script that is exported as package module and two functions. `getfirst` and `getsecond` need to access the variables that are passed from index.js like `'a', 'b'` from  `parsefile('a', 'b', 'c')`. Other than using `global`, do we have another way to do it?

```
// index.js from some application
const parsefile = require('./parsefile')
parsefile('a', 'b', 'c')


//parsefile.js exports about package module
function getfirst() {
  if (global.f && global.s) {
    return `i have totally 2 arguments: ${global.f}///${global.s}`
  }
  return `first arguments is ${global.f}`
}

function getsecond() {
  return `second arguments is ${global.s}`
}

module.exports = (...args) => {
  global.f = args[0];
  global.s = args[1];
  Promise.all([getfirst(), getsecond()]).then(([first, second]) => {
    console.log(`return from getfirst: ${first}`);
    console.log(`return from getsecond: ${second}`);
  });
}
```

Answer (score 0):

No, don't use global variables! Just pass on the arguments your `parsefile` function gets via parameters to the functions you are calling:

```
function getfirst(f, s) {
  if (f && s) {
    return `i have totally 2 arguments: ${f}///${s}`;
  }
  return `first arguments is ${global.f}`;
}

function getsecond(s) {
  return `second arguments is ${s}`
}

module.exports = (f, s) => {
  Promise.all([
    getfirst(f, s),
    getsecond(s)
  ]).then(([first, second]) => {
    console.log(`return from getfirst: ${first}`);
    console.log(`return from getsecond: ${second}`);
  });
};
```

Comment: What is the reason not to use global?

Comment: @jacobcan118 See [Why are global variables considered bad practice?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/10525582/1048572) and more