# How do I make this HTTPS connection persistent in Beast?

Tags: c++, multithreading, https, boost-asio, boost-beast

I'm making about 30,000 queries to a GraphQL server; because I have a high-latency connection, I'm doing many queries in parallel, using threads. Currently each query makes a new connection; I'd like to reuse the connections, which should reduce the time the whole download takes. Here's my code:

```
#include <boost/asio.hpp>
#include <boost/asio/ssl.hpp>
#include <boost/beast.hpp>
#include <boost/beast/ssl.hpp>
#include <boost/asio/ssl/error.hpp>
#include <boost/asio/ssl/stream.hpp>
#include <chrono>
#include <vector>
#include <array>
#include <iostream>
#include "http.h"

namespace beast=boost::beast;
namespace http=beast::http;
namespace net=boost::asio;
namespace ssl=net::ssl;
using tcp=net::ip::tcp;
using namespace std;
namespace cr=chrono;

struct TimeBytes
/* Used to compute the latency and data rate, which will be used
 * to compute the number of I/O threads for the next run.
 */
{
  float ms;
  int bytes;
};

cr::steady_clock clk;
vector<TimeBytes> timeBytes;
mutex timeBytesMutex;
thread_local string lastProto,lastHost,lastPort;

array<string,4> parseUrl(string url)
// protocol, hostname, port, path. All are strings, including the port.
{
  size_t pos0=url.find("://");
  size_t pos1;
  array<string,4> ret;
  ret[0]=url.substr(0,pos0);
  if (pos0<url.length())
    pos0+=3;
  pos1=url.find("/",pos0);
  ret[1]=url.substr(pos0,pos1-pos0);
  ret[3]=url.substr(pos1);
  pos0=ret[1].find(":");
  if (pos0<ret[1].length())
  {
    ret[2]=ret[1].substr(pos0+1);
    ret[1]=ret[1].substr(0,pos0);
  }
  else
    if (ret[0]=="https")
      ret[2]="443";
    else if (ret[0]=="https")
      ret[2]="80";
    else
      ret[2]="0";
  return ret;
}

string httpPost(string url,string data)
{
  net::io_context context;
  ssl::context ctx(ssl::context::tlsv12_client);
  tcp::resolver res(context);
  tcp::resolver::results_type endpoints;
  beast::ssl_stream<beast::tcp_stream> stream(context,ctx);
  array<string,4> parsed=parseUrl(url);
  http::request<http::string_body> req;
  http::response<http::string_body> resp;
  beast::flat_buffer buffer;
  TimeBytes tb;
  cr::nanoseconds elapsed;
  cr::time_point<cr::steady_clock> timeStart=clk.now();
  //if (parsed[0]==lastProto && parsed[1]==lastHost && parsed[2]==lastPort)
    //cout<<"same host\n";
  //load_root_certificates(ctx);
  try
  {
    ctx.set_verify_mode(ssl::verify_peer);
    endpoints=res.resolve(parsed[1],parsed[2]);
    beast::get_lowest_layer(stream).connect(endpoints);
    SSL_set_tlsext_host_name(stream.native_handle(),parsed[1].c_str());
    if (parsed[0]=="https")
      stream.handshake(net::ssl::stream_base::client);
    req.method(http::verb::post);
    req.target(parsed[3]);
    req.set(http::field::host,parsed[1]);
    req.set(http::field::connection,"keep-alive");
    req.set(http::field::user_agent,BOOST_BEAST_VERSION_STRING);
    req.set(http::field::content_type,"application/json");
    req.set(http::field::accept,"application/json");
    req.body()=data;
    req.prepare_payload();
    http::write(stream,req);
    http::read(stream,buffer,resp);
    elapsed=clk.now()-timeStart;
    tb.ms=elapsed.count()/1e6;
    tb.bytes=req.body().size()+resp.body().size()+7626;
    // 7626 accounts for HTTP, TCP, IP, and Ethernet headers.
    timeBytesMutex.lock();
    timeBytes.push_back(tb);
    timeBytesMutex.unlock();
    beast::close_socket(beast::get_lowest_layer(stream));
    if (DEBUG_QUERY)
    {
      cout<<parsed[0]<<"|\n"<<parsed[1]<<"|\n"<<parsed[2]<<"|\n"<<parsed[3]<<"|\n";
      cout<<data<<"|\n";
    }
  }
  catch (...)
  {
  }
  lastProto=parsed[0];
  lastHost=parsed[1];
  lastPort=parsed[2];
  return resp.body();
}
```

Most of the requests are to one server. A few GET requests are made to another server (using an `httpGet` function which is pretty similar to `httpPost`). After I download the data, I crunch them, so I'd like to close the connections before starting to crunch.

I tried making `context`, `ctx`, and `stream` thread-local, and `stream.shutdown()` and `context.restart()` before `close_socket()`, but the program crashed the second time the main thread called `httpPost`, from `http::read` throwing an error. (A worker thread made one query between the main thread's two queries.) At that point I was not trying to keep the connection open, but trying to make thread-local work so that I could keep the connection open.

Comment: you'll need to refactor your code to not use [global variables](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10525582/why-are-global-variables-considered-bad-practice), a class would help here, have each thread have its own instance of a connection class and store the socket in there

Answer (score 6):

I'd strongly suggest using async interfaces. Since the majority of time is obviously spent waiting for the IO, you likely can get all the throughput from just a single thread.

Here's an example that does answer your question (how to keep a client open for more than one request) while making the processing asynchronous. Right now, the downside is that all requests on a single client need to be sequenced (that's what I used the `_tasks` queue for). However this should probably serve as inspiration.

Note that the initiation functions work with all completion handler result types: `net::use_future`, `net::spawn` (coroutines) etc.

**[Live On Compiler Explorer](https://godbolt.org/z/G5sqhM9Ej)**

```
#include <boost/asio.hpp>
#include <boost/asio/ssl.hpp>
#include <boost/beast.hpp>
#include <boost/beast/ssl.hpp>
#include <chrono>
#include <deque>
#include <iomanip>
#include <iostream>

namespace net   = boost::asio;
namespace ssl   = net::ssl;
namespace beast = boost::beast;
namespace http  = beast::http;
using clk       = std::chrono::steady_clock;
using net::ip::tcp;
using beast::error_code;

using namespace std::chrono_literals;

/* Used to compute the latency and data rate, which will be used to compute the
 * number of I/O threads for the next run.  */
struct TimeBytes {
    long double ms;
    size_t      bytes;
};

static std::vector<TimeBytes> timeBytes;
static std::mutex             timeBytesMutex;

struct Url {
    struct Spec {
        std::string hostname, port;

        bool operator<(Spec const& rhs) const {
            return std::tie(hostname, port) < std::tie(rhs.hostname, rhs.port);
        }
    };
    std::string protocol, hostname, port, path;

    Spec specification() const { return {hostname, port}; }
};

#include <boost/spirit/home/x3.hpp>
#include <boost/fusion/adapted/std_tuple.hpp>
namespace x3 = boost::spirit::x3;

Url parseUrl(std::string const& url)
{
    Url ret;
    std::string hostport;
    {
        static const auto url_ = *(x3::char_ - "://") >> "://" // protocol
            >> +~x3::char_('/')                                // hostname
            >> *x3::char_;                                     // path
        auto into = std::tie(ret.protocol, hostport, ret.path);
        parse(begin(url), end(url), x3::expect[url_], into);
    }

    {
        static const auto portspec_ = (':' >> x3::uint_) >> x3::eoi;
        static const auto hostport_ =
            x3::raw[+(+~x3::char_(':') | !portspec_ >> x3::char_)] //
            >> -portspec_;

        boost::optional<uint16_t> port;
        auto into = std::tie(ret.hostname, port);
        parse(begin(hostport), end(hostport), x3::expect[hostport_], into);

        if (port.has_value())             { ret.port = std::to_string(*port); } 
        else if (ret.protocol == "https") { ret.port = "443";                 } 
        else if (ret.protocol == "http")  { ret.port = "80";                  } 
        else                              { ret.port = "0";                   } 
    }

    return ret;
}

struct Client : std::enable_shared_from_this<Client> {
  public:
    Client(net::any_io_executor ex, Url::Spec spec, ssl::context& ctx)
        : _executor(ex)
        , _spec(spec)
        , _sslcontext(ctx)
    {
    }

    template <typename Token>
    auto async_request(http::verb verb, std::string const& path,
                       std::string const& data, Token&& token)
    {
        using R = typename net::async_result<std::decay_t<Token>,
                                             void(error_code, std::string)>;
        using H = typename R::completion_handler_type;
        H handler(std::forward<Token>(token));
        R result(handler);

        auto chain_tasks = [this, h = std::move(handler),
                            self = shared_from_this()](auto&&... args) mutable {
            if (!self->_tasks.empty()) {
                dispatch(self->_executor, [this, self] {
                    if (not _tasks.empty()) _tasks.pop_front();
                    if (not _tasks.empty()) _tasks.front()->initiate();
                });
            }

            std::move(h)(std::forward<decltype(args)>(args)...);
        };

        auto task = std::make_shared<RequestOp<decltype(chain_tasks)>>(
            this, verb, path, data, chain_tasks);

        enqueue(std::move(task));

        return result.get();
    }

    template <typename Token>
    auto async_post(std::string const& path, std::string const& data,
                    Token&& token)
    {
        return async_request(http::verb::post,path, data, std::forward<Token>(token));
    }

    template <typename Token>
    auto async_get(std::string const& path, Token&& token)
    {
        return async_request(http::verb::get,path, "", std::forward<Token>(token));
    }

  private:
    template <typename Token> auto async_reconnect(Token&& token)
    {
        using R = typename net::async_result<std::decay_t<Token>, void(error_code)>;
        using H = typename R::completion_handler_type;
        H handler(std::forward<Token>(token));
        R result(handler);

        assert(!_stream.has_value()); // probably a program flow bu
        _stream.emplace(_executor, _sslcontext);

        std::make_shared<ReconnectOp<H>>(this, std::move(handler))->start();

        return result.get();
    }

    template <typename Handler>
    struct ReconnectOp : std::enable_shared_from_this<ReconnectOp<Handler>> {
        ReconnectOp(Client* client, Handler h)
            : _client{client}
            , _handler(std::move(h))
            , _resolver(client->_stream->get_executor())
        {
        }

        Client*       _client;
        Handler       _handler;
        tcp::resolver _resolver;

        bool checked(error_code ec, bool complete = false) {
            if (complete || ec)
                std::move(_handler)(ec);
            if (ec && _client->_stream.has_value())
            {
                std::cerr << "Socket " << _client->_stream->native_handle()
                          << " closed due to " << ec.message() << std::endl;
                _client->_stream.reset();
            }

            return !ec.failed();
        }

        void start()
        {
            _resolver.async_resolve(
                _client->_spec.hostname, _client->_spec.port,
                beast::bind_front_handler(&ReconnectOp::on_resolved,
                                          this->shared_from_this()));
        }

        void on_resolved(error_code ec, tcp::resolver::results_type ep)
        {
            if (checked(ec)) {
                beast::get_lowest_layer(*_client->_stream)
                    .async_connect(
                        ep,
                        beast::bind_front_handler(&ReconnectOp::on_connected,
                                                  this->shared_from_this()));
            }
        }

        void on_connected(error_code ec, tcp::endpoint ep) {
            if (checked(ec)) {
                std::cerr << "Socket " << _client->_stream->native_handle()
                          << " (re)connected to " << ep << std::endl;

                auto& hostname = _client->_spec.hostname;
                SSL_set_tlsext_host_name(_client->_stream->native_handle(),
                                         hostname.c_str());

                _client->_stream->async_handshake(
                    Stream::client,
                    beast::bind_front_handler(&ReconnectOp::on_ready,
                                              this->shared_from_this()));
            }
        }

        void on_ready(error_code ec) {
            checked(ec, true);
        }
    };

    struct IAsyncTask {
        virtual void initiate() = 0;
    };

    template <typename Handler>
    struct RequestOp : IAsyncTask, std::enable_shared_from_this<RequestOp<Handler>> {
        RequestOp(Client* client, http::verb verb, std::string const& path,
                  std::string data, Handler h)
            : _client(client)
            , _handler(std::move(h))
            , _request(verb, path, 11, std::move(data))
        {
            _request.set(http::field::host,         _client->_spec.hostname);
            _request.set(http::field::connection,   "keep-alive");
            _request.set(http::field::user_agent,   BOOST_BEAST_VERSION_STRING);
            _request.set(http::field::content_type, "application/json");
            _request.set(http::field::accept,       "application/json");
            _request.prepare_payload();
        }

        Client*                           _client;
        Handler                           _handler;
        http::request<http::string_body>  _request;
        http::response<http::string_body> _response;
        beast::flat_buffer                _buffer;
        size_t                            _bandwidth = 0;
        clk::time_point                   _start = clk::now();

        bool checked(error_code ec, bool complete = false) {
            if (complete || ec)
                std::move(_handler)(ec, std::move(_response.body()));
            if (ec)
                _client->_stream.reset();

            return !ec.failed();
        }

        void initiate() override
        {
            if (!_client->_stream.has_value()) {
                _client->async_reconnect(beast::bind_front_handler(
                    &RequestOp::on_connected, this->shared_from_this()));
            } else {
                on_connected(error_code{});
            }
        }

        void on_connected(error_code ec) {
            _start = clk::now(); // This matches the start of measurements in
                                 // the original, synchronous code
            http::async_write(*_client->_stream, _request,
                              beast::bind_front_handler(
                                  &RequestOp::on_sent, this->shared_from_this()));
        }

        void on_sent(error_code ec, size_t transferred) {
            _bandwidth += transferred; // measuring actual bytes including HTTP headers

            if (checked(ec)) {
                http::async_read(
                    *_client->_stream, _buffer, _response,
                    beast::bind_front_handler(&RequestOp::on_response,
                                              this->shared_from_this()));
            }
        }

        void on_response(error_code ec, size_t transferred) {
            _bandwidth += transferred; // measuring actual bytes including HTTP headers

            std::lock_guard lk(timeBytesMutex);
            timeBytes.push_back({(clk::now() - _start) / 1.0ms, _bandwidth});

            checked(ec, true);
        }
    };

  private:
    net::any_io_executor _executor;
    Url::Spec            _spec;
    ssl::context&        _sslcontext;

    using Stream = beast::ssl_stream<beast::tcp_stream>;
    std::optional<Stream> _stream; // nullopt when disconnected

    // task queueing
    using AsyncTask = std::shared_ptr<IAsyncTask>;
    std::deque<AsyncTask> _tasks;

    void enqueue(AsyncTask task) {
        post(_executor,
             [=, t = std::move(task), this, self = shared_from_this()] {
                 _tasks.push_back(std::move(t));
                 if (_tasks.size() == 1) {
                     _tasks.front()->initiate();
                 }
             });
    }
};

int main()
{
    ssl::context ctx(ssl::context::tlsv12_client);
    ctx.set_verify_mode(ssl::verify_peer);
    ctx.set_default_verify_paths();
    // load_root_certificates(ctx);

    net::thread_pool io(1);
    std::map<Url::Spec, std::shared_ptr<Client> > pool;

    using V = http::verb;
    for (auto [url, verb, data] : {
     std::tuple //
     {"https://httpbin.org/post",                        V::post,    "post data"},
     {"https://httpbin.org/delay/5",                     V::delete_, ""},
     {"https://httpbin.org/base64/ZGVjb2RlZCBiYXM2NA==", V::get,     ""},
     {"https://httpbin.org/delay/7",                     V::patch,   ""},
     {"https://httpbin.org/stream/3",                    V::get,     ""},
     {"https://httpbin.org/uuid",                        V::get,     ""},
    }) //
    {
        auto parsed = parseUrl(url);
        std::cout << std::quoted(parsed.protocol) << " "
                  << std::quoted(parsed.hostname) << " "
                  << std::quoted(parsed.port) << " "
                  << std::quoted(parsed.path) << "\n";

        auto spec = parsed.specification();

        if (!pool.contains(spec)) {
            pool.emplace(spec,
                         std::make_shared<Client>(
                             make_strand(io.get_executor()), spec, ctx));
        }

        pool.at(spec)->async_request(
            verb, parsed.path, data,
            [=, v = verb, u = url](error_code ec, std::string const& body) {
                std::cout << v << " to " << u << ": " << std::quoted(body)
                          << std::endl;
            });
    }

    io.join();

    for (auto& [time, bytes] : timeBytes) {
        std::cout << bytes << " bytes in " << time << "ms\n";
    }
}
```

On my system this prints

```
"https" "httpbin.org" "443" "/post"
"https" "httpbin.org" "443" "/delay/5"
"https" "httpbin.org" "443" "/base64/ZGVjb2RlZCBiYXM2NA=="
"https" "httpbin.org" "443" "/delay/7"
"https" "httpbin.org" "443" "/stream/3"
"https" "httpbin.org" "443" "/uuid"
Socket 0x7f4ad4001060 (re)connected to 18.232.227.86:443
POST to https://httpbin.org/post: "{
  \"args\": {}, 
  \"data\": \"post data\", 
  \"files\": {}, 
  \"form\": {}, 
  \"headers\": {
    \"Accept\": \"application/json\", 
    \"Content-Length\": \"9\", 
    \"Content-Type\": \"application/json\", 
    \"Host\": \"httpbin.org\", 
    \"User-Agent\": \"Boost.Beast/318\", 
    \"X-Amzn-Trace-Id\": \"Root=1-618b513c-2c51c112061b10456a5e3d4e\"
  }, 
  \"json\": null, 
  \"origin\": \"163.158.244.77\", 
  \"url\": \"https://httpbin.org/post\"
}
"
DELETE to https://httpbin.org/delay/5: "{
  \"args\": {}, 
  \"data\": \"\", 
  \"files\": {}, 
  \"form\": {}, 
  \"headers\": {
    \"Accept\": \"application/json\", 
    \"Content-Type\": \"application/json\", 
    \"Host\": \"httpbin.org\", 
    \"User-Agent\": \"Boost.Beast/318\", 
    \"X-Amzn-Trace-Id\": \"Root=1-618b513c-324c97504eb79d8b743c6c5d\"
  }, 
  \"origin\": \"163.158.244.77\", 
  \"url\": \"https://httpbin.org/delay/5\"
}
"
GET to https://httpbin.org/base64/ZGVjb2RlZCBiYXM2NA==: "decoded bas64"
PATCH to https://httpbin.org/delay/7: "{
  \"args\": {}, 
  \"data\": \"\", 
  \"files\": {}, 
  \"form\": {}, 
  \"headers\": {
    \"Accept\": \"application/json\", 
    \"Content-Type\": \"application/json\", 
    \"Host\": \"httpbin.org\", 
    \"User-Agent\": \"Boost.Beast/318\", 
    \"X-Amzn-Trace-Id\": \"Root=1-618b5141-3a8c30e60562df583061fc5a\"
  }, 
  \"origin\": \"163.158.244.77\", 
  \"url\": \"https://httpbin.org/delay/7\"
}
"
GET to https://httpbin.org/stream/3: "{\"url\": \"https://httpbin.org/stream/3\", \"args\": {}, \"headers\": {\"Host\": \"httpbin.org\", \"X-Amzn-Trace-Id\": \"Root=1-618b5148-45fce8a8432930a006c0a574\", \"User-Agent\": \"Boost.Beast/318\", \"Content-Type\": \"application/json\", \"Accept\": \"application/json\"}, \"origin\": \"163.158.244.77\", \"id\": 0}
{\"url\": \"https://httpbin.org/stream/3\", \"args\": {}, \"headers\": {\"Host\": \"httpbin.org\", \"X-Amzn-Trace-Id\": \"Root=1-618b5148-45fce8a8432930a006c0a574\", \"User-Agent\": \"Boost.Beast/318\", \"Content-Type\": \"application/json\", \"Accept\": \"application/json\"}, \"origin\": \"163.158.244.77\", \"id\": 1}
{\"url\": \"https://httpbin.org/stream/3\", \"args\": {}, \"headers\": {\"Host\": \"httpbin.org\", \"X-Amzn-Trace-Id\": \"Root=1-618b5148-45fce8a8432930a006c0a574\", \"User-Agent\": \"Boost.Beast/318\", \"Content-Type\": \"application/json\", \"Accept\": \"application/json\"}, \"origin\": \"163.158.244.77\", \"id\": 2}
"
GET to https://httpbin.org/uuid: "{
  \"uuid\": \"4557c909-880e-456c-8ef9-049a72f5fda1\"
}
"
826 bytes in 84.9807ms
752 bytes in 5267.26ms
425 bytes in 84.6031ms
751 bytes in 7085.28ms
1280 bytes in 86.6554ms
434 bytes in 85.0086ms
```

Note:

- httpbin.org has all manner of test urls - some of which generate long delays, hence the timings
- there's only 1 connection. In case of an IO error, we disconnect (and things should reconnect on the next request)
- HTTP errors are not "errors" in that the connection stays valid
- The DNS resolve, connect and handshake are also asynchronous

Comment: This comment gave a great insight! Thank you @sehe!

Comment: Great example.
One thing that seems broken (using boost 1.83) is the parseUrl function. If the port is not specified, it parses as if it specified but 0. 
It's been 10 years since I looked at Boost Spirit, so I can't figure it out. :)

Comment: @RuiFig Thanks for spotting that. It was actually a bug (double optionalization) that only manifested since [703ec53 X3: Optional parser is not a passthrough parser](https://github.com/boostorg/spirit/commit/703ec533d8cc4ab1cffe04572434652b77541556) (boost 1.77.0)

Comment: @sehe I see the request token doesn't get back the actual HTTP status code. Is that intentional? The caller will get the body but not know if it was an HTTP error or not. Unless I'm missing something. I had some experience with asio years ago, but zero experience with HTTP/Beast.