# Possible improvements in terms of performance while sending http requests using boost::beast

Tags: optimization, networking, c++17, boost-asio, boost-beast

I am building a low latency project and sending http requests as fast as possible is a key component. Here's the construction of my current http request

```
#include <thread>
#include <iostream>
#include <coroutine>
#include <optional>
#include <variant>
#include <vector>
#include <utility>
#include <string>
#include <chrono>

#include <boost/asio.hpp>
#include <boost/asio/ssl.hpp>
#include <boost/json.hpp>
#include <boost/beast.hpp>
#include <boost/asio/io_context.hpp>
#include <boost/asio/ssl/context.hpp>
#include <boost/asio/ip/tcp.hpp>
#include <boost/asio/spawn.hpp>
#include <boost/coroutine/all.hpp>
#include <boost/beast/ssl/ssl_stream.hpp>
#include <boost/beast/core/tcp_stream.hpp>
#include <boost/beast/core/flat_static_buffer.hpp>
#include <boost/beast/http.hpp>
#include <boost/beast/http/string_body.hpp>
#include <boost/beast/http/verb.hpp>
#include <boost/asio/awaitable.hpp>
#include <boost/asio/detached.hpp>

class http_client {
private:
    using response = boost::beast::http::response<boost::beast::http::string_body>;

    std::string http_hostname;
    std::string ip_address;
    boost::asio::ssl::context ssl_context;
    boost::asio::ip::tcp::resolver hostname_resolver;
    std::optional<boost::beast::ssl_stream<boost::beast::tcp_stream>> tcp_stream;
    boost::beast::flat_static_buffer<4 * 1024 * 1024> receive_flat_buffer;
public:
    http_client(const std::string& http_name, boost::asio::io_context& io_context) :
        http_hostname(http_name),
        ssl_context(boost::asio::ssl::context::tlsv12_client),
        hostname_resolver(io_context),
        tcp_stream(boost::beast::ssl_stream<boost::beast::tcp_stream>(io_context, ssl_context)),
        receive_flat_buffer()
    {

        ssl_context.set_verify_mode(boost::asio::ssl::verify_peer);
        ssl_context.set_options(
            boost::asio::ssl::context::default_workarounds | boost::asio::ssl::context::no_sslv2 |
            boost::asio::ssl::context::no_sslv3 | boost::asio::ssl::context::single_dh_use);

        if (!SSL_set_tlsext_host_name(tcp_stream->native_handle(), http_hostname.c_str())) {
            boost::beast::error_code error_code{static_cast<int>(::ERR_get_error()), boost::asio::error::get_ssl_category()};
            throw boost::beast::system_error{error_code};
        }

        auto const resolved_endpoint = hostname_resolver.resolve(http_hostname, "443");
        ip_address = resolved_endpoint->endpoint().address().to_string();

        boost::beast::get_lowest_layer(tcp_stream.value()).connect(resolved_endpoint);
        boost::beast::get_lowest_layer(tcp_stream.value()).socket().set_option(boost::asio::socket_base::keep_alive(true));
        boost::beast::get_lowest_layer(tcp_stream.value()).socket().set_option(boost::asio::ip::tcp::no_delay(true));

        std::cout << "Connected to REST endpoint at IP address <" << ip_address << "> which was resolved from <" << resolved_endpoint->host_name() << std::endl;
        tcp_stream->handshake(boost::asio::ssl::stream_base::client);
    }


    void send_request(boost::asio::io_context& io_context, const std::string& target, const std::function<void(response)>& callback) {
        boost::asio::spawn(
            io_context, [target = std::move(target), callback = std::move(callback), this](boost::asio::yield_context yield_context) mutable
            {
                boost::beast::http::request<boost::beast::http::string_body> http_request{
                    boost::beast::http::verb::get,
                    target,
                    11};

                http_request.set(boost::beast::http::field::host, http_hostname);
                http_request.set(boost::beast::http::field::content_type, "application/json");
                http_request.set(boost::beast::http::field::connection, "Keep-Alive");
                http_request.set(boost::beast::http::field::keep_alive, "timeout=86400");
                http_request.keep_alive(true);
                http_request.prepare_payload();

                size_t bytes_transferred = boost::beast::http::async_write(tcp_stream.value(), http_request, yield_context);

                response http_response;
                boost::beast::http::async_read(tcp_stream.value(), receive_flat_buffer, http_response, yield_context);

                callback(http_response);
            }
        );
    }
};

int main() {
    boost::asio::io_context io_context{};

    std::string host_name{"fapi.binance.com"};
    http_client client(host_name, io_context);

    for (int i = 0; i < 100; i++) {
        auto const stime = std::chrono::duration_cast<std::chrono::nanoseconds>(std::chrono::system_clock::now().time_since_epoch()).count();
        client.send_request(io_context, "/fapi/v1/time", [&](boost::beast::http::response<boost::beast::http::string_body> const& http_response) {});

        auto const etime = std::chrono::duration_cast<std::chrono::nanoseconds>(std::chrono::system_clock::now().time_since_epoch()).count();
        std::cout << "time diff = " << etime - stime << std::endl;
        std::this_thread::sleep_for(std::chrono::milliseconds(100));
    }

    io_context.run();

    return 0;
}
```

And here are the compiler flags I am using

```
g++ -std=c++20 -O2 -flto -g beast_http_client.cpp -I/home/dev/vcpkg/installed/x64-linux/include -L/home/dev/vcpkg/installed/x64-linux/lib -lboost_system -lboost_coroutine -lboost_thread -lboost_json -lssl -lcrypto -lboost_context
```

I timed this and the latency varies around 10-20 us on average. I was wondering whether there are any improvements I can do to bring this around to low single digit micro. I know boost::beast is quite a heavy library but yeah, thought I would learn from the experts regarding obvious optimisations

Hardware: I am running this on AWS virtual machine with Intel Xeon processor 3GHz

Comment: TCP is not really well suited for low latency, especially if you are close to the target machine on a safe connection (i.e. almost no errors). Disabling Nagle help though. SSL does not help either because it adds another hand-check on top of TCP (though security matter for financial systems except if you are in a trusted environment). You need to measure the RTT of the connection to find out how efficient the program is in term of latency.

Comment: I do not think using boost is optimal for performance but I am not sure of its implementation. It looks like it use the old API for async IO operations which tends not to scale with many connections (and introduce a high latency in this case). Only few libraries implement the new fast OS async interfaces (sad). Things like kqueue, io_uring, etc. They can be far more efficient if performance is critical though they are also low-level. There is no free lunch, especially at the scale of micro-seconds (1 syscall typically cost generally at least several micro-seconds).

Comment: What are you trying to measure? The value measured here measures **ONLY** initiation of the async operation. Even if you measured the time between that and the completion, that's not what "latency" usually means

Answer (score 0):

There are *many* issues.

Like I mentioned in my comments, it's unclear what you're trying to measure (and calling "latency", somehow).

But reading on, it becomes clear that the code is broken in many more ways.

The `main` loop schedules 100 coroutines, waiting 100ms between each (for no reason at all), then, only at the end of main executes all of them at once by invoking `io_context.run()`.

This not only creates something similar to a denial-of-service attack on the server, it also clearly violates the restrictions that only one write operation can be in flight at one time (this goes for SSL streams in particular, but also for the underlying POSIX internet domain stream socket).

> In fact, if you ran a Debug build, no doubt there would have been assertions like these aborting the program for you:
> sotest:
>
> ```
> /home/sehe/custom/superboost/boost/beast/core/detail/stream_base.hpp:116: void boost::beast::detail::stream_base::pending_guard::assign(bool&): Assertion `! *b_' failed.
> ```

Some other issues include:
Fixing these and some reability concerns:

- you regularly `move` from const variables. Not very useful
- you're redundantly passing `io_context` references instead of using executors
- you might be setting socket options late
- you're using `optional<>` for no reason. If you must, at least use `stream_(std::in_place, ...)` for the construction
- std::function introduces type-erasure (virtual dispatch) and copying
- you probably want to time the start-completion (roundtrip) time
- you use a `string_body` instead of `empty_body` on a GET request

**[Live On Coliru](https://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/99d0a525f8456ab4)**

```cpp
#include <iomanip>
#include <iostream>

#include <boost/asio.hpp>
#include <boost/asio/spawn.hpp>
#include <boost/asio/ssl.hpp>
#include <boost/beast.hpp>
#include <boost/beast/ssl.hpp>

namespace net   = boost::asio;
namespace ssl   = net::ssl;
namespace beast = boost::beast;
namespace http  = beast::http;
using beast::error_code;
using net::ip::tcp;
using namespace std::chrono_literals;

static constexpr auto now = std::chrono::steady_clock::now;
using duration            = std::chrono::steady_clock::duration;

class http_client {
  private:
    using Stream  = beast::ssl_stream<beast::tcp_stream>;

    std::string  host_;
    ssl::context ctx_{ssl::context::tlsv12_client};
    Stream       stream_;

    std::string                        ip_address;
    beast::flat_static_buffer<4 << 10> buf_;

  public:
    using response = http::response<http::string_body>;

    http_client(std::string host, net::io_context& ioc) : host_(std::move(host)), stream_(ioc, ctx_) {
        ctx_.set_verify_mode(ssl::verify_peer);
        using C = ssl::context;
        ctx_.set_options(C::default_workarounds | C::no_sslv2 | C::no_sslv3 | C::single_dh_use);

        if (!SSL_set_tlsext_host_name(stream_.native_handle(), host_.c_str()))
            throw beast::system_error(::ERR_get_error(), net::error::get_ssl_category());

        auto eps   = tcp::resolver(ioc).resolve(host_, "443");
        ip_address = eps->endpoint().address().to_string();

        {
            auto& ll = beast::get_lowest_layer(stream_);
            auto& s  = ll.socket();
            s.open(tcp::v4());
            s.set_option(tcp::no_delay(true));
            s.set_option(tcp::socket::keep_alive(true));
            ll.connect(eps);
        }

        std::cout << "Connected to REST endpoint at IP address " << quoted(ip_address)
                  << " which was resolved from " << quoted(eps->host_name()) << std::endl;
        stream_.handshake(Stream::client);
    }

    // template <typename F>
    // requires std::invocable<F, error_code, response, duration>
    void send_request(std::string target, std::function<void(error_code, response, duration)> callback) {
        spawn(stream_.get_executor(),
              [start = now(), target = std::move(target), cb = std::move(callback),
               this](net::yield_context yield) mutable {
                  http::request<http::empty_body> http_request{http::verb::get, target, 11};

                  http_request.set(http::field::host, host_);
                  http_request.set(http::field::content_type, "application/json");
                  http_request.set(http::field::connection, "Keep-Alive");
                  http_request.set(http::field::keep_alive, "timeout=86400");
                  http_request.keep_alive(true);
                  http_request.prepare_payload();

                  /*size_t bytes_transferred =*/async_write(stream_, http_request, yield);

                  response http_response;
                  error_code ec;
                  async_read(stream_, buf_, http_response, yield[ec]);

                  std::move(cb)(ec, std::move(http_response), now() - start);
              });
    }
};

void send_loop(http_client& client, std::string const& target, unsigned n) {
    if (n == 0)
        return;

    client.send_request(target, [=, &client](error_code ec, http_client::response res, duration dur) {
        send_loop(client, target, n - 1); // only now it is safe to schedule a new write

        std::cout << "#" << n << " " << ec.message() << " in " << (dur / 1ms) << " ms";
        if (!ec)
            std::cout << " HTTP " << res.reason();
        std::cout << std::endl;
    });
}

int main() {
    net::io_context io_context;

    http_client client("fapi.binance.com", io_context);
    send_loop(client, "/fapi/v1/time", 3);

    io_context.run();
}
```

Locally demoed:

[image]

### Other Issues/Improvements

- You're relying on the connection to never fail
- Common HTTP server implementation limit the number of pipelined requests
- You are using the default type erased executors (`any_io_executor`)
- You are using stackful coroutines, which are a bit heavy

You should probably consider a separate IO thread and possibly multiple connections. See e.g. [How do I make this HTTPS connection persistent in Beast?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69896335/how-do-i-make-this-https-connection-persistent-in-beast/69908177#69908177) for ideas to progress from here.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestions. The main loop is not part of our main logic and I admit it was half baked. I will take your suggestions for the core implementation and give that a shot