# How to import file globally in node js

Tags: node.js

I have created a `helper.js` file that will contain `helper functions`. In order to use the helper functions, I have to import the file in all the locations where I want it to be used. Is there any way I can `load/import` the `helper.js` file `globally`?

> helper.js

```
module.exports = {
    responseObject: function (status, message, data, error) {
        return {
            status: status,
            message: message,
            data: data,
            error: error
        }
    }
}
```

> index.js

```
// load mongoose
require('./db/mongoose')

const express = require('express')
const app = express()
const port = process.env.PORT || 3000

app.use(helper)

// load routers
const userRouter = require('./routers/user')

app.use(express.json())     // automatically converts incoming requests to json
app.use(userRouter)

app.listen(port)
```

> UserController.js

```
const User = require("../models/user")
const helper = require("../helper")

exports.createUser = async (req, res) => {
    const user = new User(req.body)

    try {
        await user.save()
        res.status(201).send({
            status: true,
            message: 'Registration success',
            data: user,
            error: {}
        })
    } catch (error) {
        const response = helper.responseObject(false, "Wrong", {}, error)
        res.status(400).send(response);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From the [documentation](https://nodejs.org/api/globals.html#global):

> In browsers, the top-level scope is the global scope. This means that
> within the browser var something will define a new global variable. In
> Node.js this is different. The top-level scope is not the global
> scope; var something inside a Node.js module will be local to that
> module.

This means you can't just define your `responseObject` in the "global" scope, as it always refers to the scope local to the module and will not be available to other modules.

But there's a way to do it, although I ***would not*** recommend it (search Google or [SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10525582/why-are-global-variables-considered-bad-practice) why that's the case, this has been discussed in detail already). You can add your `function/variable` to the `global` object (which is somewhat similar to the `window` keyword in browsers):

```
// in your app.js "add" the exported stuff from the helper-module to the global object
const express = require('express')
...
global.myHelper = require('./helper');


// in e.g. your user-controller you could then access it like
const response = global.myHelper.responseObject(false, "Wrong", {}, error)
```