# (window as any).globalstorage, any caveats?

Tags: javascript, html, typescript, vue.js, vue-component

After trying to get several more commonly suggested methods of getting data from one Vue page to another and failing, I found `(window as any).storagename = datatostore;` to be an incredibly easy to use method to store and then retrieve information with `retrievedata = (window as any).storagename` from anywhere in my project to anywhere.

I am wondering however if there are downsides or potential issues I should be aware of? Since this method is never the first option mentioned, I wonder if there is a reason it is not used as much.

Comment: Possible duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10525582/why-are-global-variables-considered-bad-practice

Comment: Also see https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/148108/why-is-global-state-so-evil . Global variables were previously used in JS due to language limitations. There's no excuse for doing this in modular environment, unless you know it's the right case for them.