# How can I import all the function from other file to current file?

Tags: javascript, node.js, typescript, cypress

I have one file containing many functions. Similar to below,

```
export const func1 = () => {
}

export const func2 = () => {
}

export const func3 = () => {
}

export const func4 = () => {
}
```

Now I want to use all this function in another file.

Method 1 is `import {func1, func2, func3, func4} from 'path'`.
Method 2 (which I don't want to use) is `import * as access from 'path'`

Method 1 approach is what I am using right now. But when func file gets bigger, this will not be readable. So, how to use the functions without creating aliases and simply `func1()` and not `access.func1()` ?

Comment: Method 1 is how you do it. If you have that many functions in a module that are so unrelated that it doesn't make sense to wrap them under a name, maybe they shouldn't be in the same module?

Answer (score 1):

You should really make up your mind between the two as they are the most readable and clean solutions.

First option can be made more readable with:

```js
import {
  func1,
  func2,
  func3,
  func4
} from 'path';
```

---

Nevertheless, if you really want an alternative syntax without having to list the exports, it is technically possible to load all the exported properties into the global object through:

```js
Object.assign(globalThis, require('path'))
```

However, I would **highly advise against this** as it'll make your code **very difficult to maintain**. [Global variables are painful enough](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10525582), but unknown global variables coming from another file will be a nightmare. Use at your own risk.

Comment: I agree with your answer, but can you add some more information on why you would advise against loading exported properties into the global object?

Comment: @agoff sure, just added a bit

Comment: Thanks :D Appreciate it.

Answer (score 1):

You can import with your Method 2 and then can use object destructuring on the access object like this and use them directly.

```
import * as access from 'path';

const {func1, func2, func3, func4} = access;

func1();
```

Comment: How is this any better than `import {func1,func2,func2,func4} from 'path';`?  You still have two write something out for every "`funcN`". This just splits it into two steps rather than one.

Comment: The question wants to keep imports readable when there is more number of functions to be imported and still use those functions without using the `importObj.functionName` notation. So, in that spirit, I think it solves the problem faced by the OP, but for which is better, I am not aware of any tangible advantages of either approach other than personal preference.