Are global variables still slower than local variables in modern JavaScript engines?
I recently read "High Performance JavaScript" (2010) which states:

The deeper into the execution context’s scope chain an identifier exists, the slower it is to access for both reads and writes. Consequently, local variables are always the fastest to access inside of a function, whereas global variables will generally be the slowest. Keep in mind that global variables always exist in the last variable object of the execution context’s scope chain, so they are always the furthest away to resolve.

Given the substantial optimizations in JavaScript engines over the past decade, I wonder is this statement still accurate in 2024?
let globalVar = 0;

function testVariables() {
    let localVar = 0;
    let globalStartTime = performance.now();

    for (let i = 0; i < 5000000; i++) {
        globalVar += 1;
    }
    let globalEndTime = performance.now();

    let localStartTime = performance.now();

    for (let i = 0; i < 5000000; i++) {
        localVar += 1;
    }
    let localEndTime = performance.now();

    console.log(`Global variable access time: ${globalEndTime - globalStartTime} ms`);
    console.log(`Local variable access time: ${localEndTime - localStartTime} ms`);
}

testVariables();

The output is:
Global variable access time: 25.80000001192093 ms
Local variable access time: 11.400000035762787 ms
It is surely that global variables take more time to be accessed than local variables, but I am still not sure that whether scope chain traversal is the main reason behind this. Perhaps there are other reasons?

The statement you have quoted from 2010 still applies today. If anything, the difference is not as great now compared to 2010 - your test suggests a 2:1 speed difference, I recollect some browsers back in 2012 (my earliest attempt at optimising a really bad design), the difference was closer to 10:1

"whether scope chain traversal is the main reason behind this" yes that's still a relatively expensive operation. Remember that variables in inner scopes can shadow ones in outer scopes, so to "look up" the name of the variable you have to start in the innermost scope and work your way out. A Javascript engine isn't magic it's just another program, and it stores identifiers for a given scope in some structure like a hashmap. So you ask the map if it has a given variable name. No? Move to the map for the next scope outward and rinse and repeat until you find it or reach the global scope.

@JaredSmith yup. In pseudo-code-ish a + 1 will have to resolve this by looking up the value of a which would be resolved similar to scope1.get("a") ?? scope2.get("a") ?? scope3.get("a") ?? ... ?? globalScope.get("a")

When you access a variable in an outer scope (not always global, an engine should make a lookup), so it's slower. Not sure why the global scope isn't updated only after the loop completes, since there're no reads in the global scope possible until the loop completes (maybe it's not possible to optimize).
With object references it's different, since no object reference is mutated and objects are allocated on the heap, so no actual difference when you mutate them.
And benchmarking:
` Chrome/125
-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
>                      n=5000       |     n=50000      |    n=500000     |    n=5000000    
local             ■ 1.00x x100k 374 | ■ 1.00x x10k 343 | ■ 1.00x x1k 268 | ■ 1.00x x100 268
object argument     1.44x x100k 539 |   1.40x x10k 479 |   1.43x x1k 384 |   1.37x x100 368
local object        1.16x x100k 435 |   1.30x x10k 445 |   1.46x x1k 392 |   1.37x x100 368
global object       1.28x x100k 479 |   1.40x x10k 480 |   1.36x x1k 364 |   1.40x x100 376
global              1.71x x100k 639 |   1.72x x10k 590 |   2.00x x1k 536 |   2.05x x100 550
outer scope         1.71x x100k 641 |   1.87x x10k 642 |   2.42x x1k 648 |   2.45x x100 657
------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------- `

Open in the playground


let globalVar = 0;
const globalObj = {var: 0};
let $length = 5000;

// @benchmark global
function loopVarG(){
  for(let i=0;i<$length;i++){
    globalVar += 1;
  }
}
// @run
loopVarG();

// @benchmark outer scope
function loopVarOS(){
  let localVar = 0;

  function loopVarOS(){
    for(let i=0;i<$length;i++){
      localVar += 1;
    }
  }

  loopVarOS();
}
// @run
loopVarOS();

// @benchmark local
function loopVar(){
  let localVar = 0;
  for(let i=0;i<$length;i++){
    localVar += 1;
  }
}
// @run
loopVar();

// @benchmark global object
function loopVarGO(){
  for(let i=0;i<$length;i++){
    globalObj.var += 1;
  }
}
// @run
loopVarGO();

// @benchmark local object
function loopVarO(){
  const localObj = {var: 0};
  for(let i=0;i<$length;i++){
    localObj.var += 1;
  }
}
// @run
loopVarO();

// @benchmark object argument
function loopVarOA(localObj){
  for(let i=0;i<$length;i++){
    localObj.var += 1;
  }
}
// @run
loopVarOA(globalObj);

/*@skip*/ fetch('https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/gh/silentmantra/benchmark/loader.js').then(r => r.text().then(eval));




Global variables are considered bad practice. See https://stackoverflow.com/a/10525602/8830502
Memory allocation issues
The internal interpreter can also allocate and manage memory better if variables are scoped as locally as possible to give used memory free after processing. See here https://wiki.c2.com/?GlobalVariablesAreBad
So there is less memory and read/write operations used and also less dependencies between other scopes and therefore it is faster.

Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers in the help center.

I think another reason is that if you have variable in the global namespace, then external can change that variable and it will force the interpreter to reload the value each time through the loop.
Hence makes it slower than local variable

the code is sync so the loop blocks the thread, no reloading is ever possible

Hmm, it's like the since scope is wide, it can be changed by outside of the function scope, so everytime we access, the interpreter like has this overhead to check to get the correct value of that variable, no? At least that's how I understand it, as one of the aspect, I could be wrong though, I'd like to know more :)
